# How to print content or page numbers using @print css3?

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to add some content when print my document using @print in my css style. But nothing is happening. Here is my code:

```css
@page {
     size:landscape;
     counter-increment: page;
        counter-reset: page 1;
        @top-right {
            content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
        };
     @top-left {
      content: "Hamlet";
        };
    }
    
    
    @media print {
     h1 {
      color: red;
     }
     
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
       <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
       <head>
       <body>
    
          <div id="content">
             <div id="pageFooter">Page </div>
             <h1>This is header</h1>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce venenatis
         </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

My header in the html is changed in red when I try to print it out but there is no page numbers or "Hamlet" in the top-left on the document.Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure these properties are already supported by the browsers?

The [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#at-ruledef-top-right-corner) is still in `Editor's Draft` state so i wouldn't bet on it already being implemented.

If you check this page [about top-right rule for print](https://www.quackit.com/css/at-rules/css_top-right-corner_at-rule.cfm) it says that the following:

> Margin at-rules can only accept page-margin properties.

They have this example:

```
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 10%;

  @top-right-corner {
    content: "Page " counter(page);
  }
}
```

Maybe you can try this out and see if this basic example already works in any browser?